# Rest Api to accept Blob input

Tags: java, api, rest, blob

I have a search-feature in my product where the user can type anything he wants. 
This string can be multi-line.

After entering the multi-line blob of data (string), the user hits on "search" button. 
This will send the "blob" to my Api.

Now I believe that this will be a POST request. (Please correct me if I am wrong here)
But I am not sure what will be the best data-structure to receive the input.

(I am using dropwizard).

How should I send the input to my api? So should my input be:

1. String
2. Array of Strings  ( where each line is one element of the array )
3. ?

I am currently sending the Blob data as a part of my POST request payload.

Comment: Why are you looking to change the way you are currently doing this? Sending the search criteria as a string makes perfect sense. The communication protocol should properly handle escaping whatever needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'blob' is not what you have. A blob is a [Binary Large Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) while the content of a `textarea` definitely is not binary but simple text.

A Java JAX-RS REST API can receive the body of a HTTP POST:

```
@POST
public Respone postSearch(@RequestBody String searchFieldContent) {
  // do search
  // return Response
}
```

I advise not to use POST for a search (which would be RPC) but GET. Build a query parameter like

```
GET /api/things?search=what the user entered into the textarea
```

which could be mapped to

```
@GET
public Response searchThings(@RequestParam("search") String searchParam) {
  // do search
  // return Response
}
```

**Edit**

Using  POST for a search is not RESTful. If you can't use GET, a better approach would be to model a search as a separate resource with state.

Client:

```
POST /api/searches

the long text the user entered in the textarea
```

Server:

```
201 Created
Location: /api/searches/id-of-search-created-by-server
```

Client

```
GET /api/searches/id-of-search-created-by-server
```

Server:

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "query": "the long text the user entered in the textarea",
  "state", "finished",
  "result": {
    "length": 23,
    "documents: [
      {
        "id": "id of first search hit",
        "title": "some title"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The only reason I am using post is a possibility of user entering a long string.

Comment: I do not want to specify a limit. So you can think of string having 10000 characters as well.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you a RESTful approach.